# Number of edge-invariant walks in complete graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a complete graph $(V,E)$ with $n$ vertices $V$ and walks $p \in V^{l+1}$ of length $l$. We say the edges of walks $p$ are the multiset

$$
e_p = \{ (p_i,p_{i+1}) \mid 1 \leq i \leq l \}.
$$
Also the frequency of vertex $v \in V$ in walk $p$ is $p[v] = |\{ i \mid p_i = v \}|$. The frequency of all vertices $f_p \in \mathbb{N}^n$ in walk $p$ is then given by
$$
f_p = [ p[v_1], p[v_2], \dots, p[v_n] ].
$$

Now, two walks $p$ and $q$ are called edge-invariant if $f_p = f_q$ and $e_p = e_q$. How many different walks of length $l$, which are not edge-invariant, exist? More precisely, i.e., 
$$
max_{P \subset V^{l+1}} | \{ P \mid \forall p, q \in P: e_p \neq e_q \textrm{ or } f_p \neq f_q \textrm{ for } p \neq q \}|.
$$

For example, $n = 2$, it's $4, 8, 14, 22, 32, 44, 58, 74, 92, 112, 134, 158$ for $l = 1,\dots,12$. Specifically for $l = 3$, out of the 16 possible walks, two are edge-invariant:
$$
e_{[1,1,2,1]} = e_{[1,2,1,1]} \textrm{ and } e_{[2,2,1,2]} = e_{[2,1,2,2]}.
$$

For $n = 3$, [it's given here](https://oeis.org/A289658) as $9, 27, 75, 186, 414, 840, 1578, 2784, 4662, 7476, 11556$ for $l = 1,\dots,11$.

It seems to be related to [k-abelian equivalence classes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.03319), where the general problem seems to be rather difficult, but maybe the 2-abelian cases is simpler?

Comment: What do you mean by complete directed graph? Tournament? Next, what is "edge invariant" - a binary relation on pairs? Then what does "how many edge-invariant paths" mean?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Sorry, I meant simply a complete graph (with edges from each vertices to any other) and not a tournament. I also clarified the edge-invariant property.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev oh yes, I'm sorry, it should be trails not paths. I will correct this

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev In fact, it's even walks

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks for the clarification. $e_p$ are multisets.

Comment: Do you want $e_p=e_q$ or $e_p\neq e_q$?

Comment: @SamHopkins I think, it should be $e_p \neq e_q$. The set P should have a representative from each equivalent class formed by the edge-invariance.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Sorry, the index was shifted by one. I correct this. Further, there are 4 walks, [1,1], [1,2], [2,1], [2,2] as order matters.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thank you very much for pointing this our. The walks should be permutations of each other. I must have dropped this accidentally in an edit. I will correct.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev You're right, I'll be more precise.

Comment: 12 versions in eight hours. Holy cow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the formula below is useful, but at least it can be used to numerically count edge-invariant walks classes for small $n,l$.

Let's assign a unique variable to each edge and each vertex of the complete graph, say, $x_{ij}$ to an edge $(i,j)$ and $y_i$ to a vertex $i$. Then, we assign to each edge $(i,j)$ the weight $x_{i,j}y_j$ and consider the graph adjacency matrix $A$. For example, for $n=4$ the matrix is
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
x_{11}y_1 & x_{12}y_2 & x_{13}y_3 & x_{14}y_4\\
x_{21}y_1 & x_{22}y_2 & x_{23}y_3 & x_{24}y_4\\
x_{31}y_1 & x_{32}y_2 & x_{33}y_3 & x_{34}y_4\\
x_{41}y_1 & x_{42}y_2 & x_{43}y_3 & x_{44}y_4
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then the number of classes of edge-invariant of length $l$ is given by the number of distinct monomial terms in
$$[y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n]\cdot A^l\cdot [1,1,\dots,1]^T.$$

For example, for $n=2$ and $l=3$ we get the polynomial:
$$x_{11}^3y_1^4 + x_{11}^2x_{12}y_1^3y_2 + x_{11}^2x_{21}y_1^3y_2 + 2x_{11}x_{12}x_{21}y_1^3y_2 + x_{11}x_{12}x_{21}y_1^2y_2^2 + x_{12}^2x_{21}y_1^2y_2^2 + x_{12}x_{21}^2y_1^2y_2^2 + x_{11}x_{12}x_{22}y_1^2y_2^2 + x_{11}x_{21}x_{22}y_1^2y_2^2 + x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}y_1^2y_2^2 + 2x_{12}x_{21}x_{22}y_1y_2^3 + x_{12}x_{22}^2y_1y_2^3 + x_{21}x_{22}^2y_1y_2^3 + x_{22}^3y_2^4,$$
where the monomials describe equivalence classes of walks (more specifically, $x$'s describe $e_p$ and $y$'s describe $f_p$) and the coefficients give the size of each class. There are $14$ distinct monomials here and only two of them have coefficient $2$, as expected.

Here is my SAGE implementation of this formula:

```
# generator for variables
class VariableGenerator(object): 
  def __init__(self, prefix): 
     self.__prefix = prefix 
  @cached_method 
  def __getitem__(self, key): 
     return SR.var("%s%s"%(self.__prefix,key)) 

def NumEIClasses2(n,l):
  x = VariableGenerator('x')
  y = VariableGenerator('y')

  R = PolynomialRing(QQ,[x[i] for i in range(n*n)] + [y[i] for i in range(n)])

  A = matrix([[x[n*i + j]*y[j] for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)])

  u = vector([1 for i in range(n)])
  Y = vector([y[i] for i in range(n)])

  P = R( (Y.row() * A^l * u.column())[0,0] )
  #print P    # print the resulting polynomial

  return P.hamming_weight()
```

For example, for $n=4$ it gives counts 16, 64, 244, 856, 2728, 7892, 20876, 51020, 116408, ...

Comment: that's certainly very helpful! Also I can confirm the solutions to $n=4$.

Comment: Although, ideally I would prefer a bit more closed Form solution. I had the impression that the generating functions for this problem are rather compact, although I don't know exactly how to get there.

Comment: @SebastianSchlecht: I doubt there is a simple general formula. But for a fixed $n$, it seems to be a polynomial in $l$. For $n=2$ and $n=3$, we have second- and sixth- degree polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, I have found an asymptotic answer [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-53132-7_7).

Define our problem in terms of k-abelian equivalence classes. Two words $u$ and $v$ are said to be $k$-abelian equivalent if, for each word $x$ of length at most $k$, the number of occurrences of $x$ as a factor of $u$ is the same as for $v$. It is easy to see the correspondence between words and walks (used in the question), and the subwords of length 1 ($f_p$) and length ($e_p$). Thus, our problem is to find the number of 2-abelian equivalence classes with length $l$ and alphabet size $n$.

In the mentioned paper (Theorem 5.1), it is shown that the number of $k$-abelian equivalence classes is asymtotically equal to $C l^{n^{k}(n-1)}$, where $C$ is a rational number dependent on $k$ and $n$.